# Convert Decimal to Date in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, date-formatting

I have a column in my table having date value as Decimal like `20180715` for the date `15-07-2018`.

I want to convert it to `MMDDYYYY` format.
Example:
Given decimal value `20180715` is converted to `07152018`.

How to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean convert for the purpose of display of a USA format date only? i.e. you don't want to change the data in the table?

Comment: Don't you think a leading zero will be problematik in a numeric data type? You have to specify what the target data type should be - I would recommend using the date data type because it is for storing dates :-)

Answer (score 3):

try somthing like this:

```
select 
VARCHAR_FORMAT( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(yourcolumn as varchar(8)), 'YYYYMMDD') , 'MMDDYYYY') 
from yourtable
```

but you you want a really date do it:

```
select 
DATE( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(cast(yourcolumn as varchar(8)), 'YYYYMMDD')) 
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query for the date

```
select 
date(timestamp_format(char(yourcolumn+19000000), 'YYYYMMDD')) 
from yourtable
```

To get the time

```
select 
cast( substr( right( '00' || yourcolumn, 6) ,1,2) || ':' || substr( right( '00' || yourcolumn, 6) ,3,2) || ':' || substr( right( '00' || yourcolumn, 6) ,5,2) as time) 
from yourtable
```